# Hide button after audio is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio

I want to hide a pause button as soon as the audio file is finished. 
I don't know why this code isn't working.

The play button ist start. Then when the audio plays the audio button becomes a pause button. But the pause button stays after the audio is finished.

What's my mistake?

```
<audio id="audio">
  <source src="../audio/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<img ng-click="playAudio()" src="../audio/play.jpg" alt="" ng-hide="!pause">
<img ng-click="pauseAudio()" src="../audio/pause.jpg" alt="" ng-hide="pause">
```

And the controller:

```
  .controller('AudioCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var vid = document.getElementById("audio");
  vid.onended = function() {
    $scope.pause = true;

  };
  $scope.pause = true;

  $scope.playAudio = function() {
      vid.play();
      $scope.pause = false;
  }

  $scope.pauseAudio = function() {
      vid.pause();
      $scope.pause = true;
  }

})
```

Comment: You might want to call `$scope.apply`

Comment: is onend getting triggered?

Comment: @ArunGhosh yes and Rayon can you make an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**`$apply()`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser `DOM events`, `setTimeout`, `XHR` or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper `scope life cycle` of `exception handling`, `executing watches`.

`VideoElement.onended` is not being invoked under the context of `Angular`. If you want to change the `model` outside the `angular-context`, you are suppose to inform angular about the changes by calling `$apply()` manually.

*It’s like telling `Angular` that you are changing some `models` and it should fire the `watchers` so that your changes propagate properly.* [*Reference*](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

```js
vid.onended = function() {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    console.log('Here');
    $scope.pause = true;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
  .controller('AudioCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  var vid = document.getElementById("audio");
  vid.onended = function() {
    $timeout(function(){
       $scope.pause = true;
    }, 0);
  };
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much =). Why is a timeout needed?